# Quill: Loading data from database shows 'True' instead of stored value

Tags: javascript, php, quill

I'm using Quill as an editor. One of the functions I made adds timestamps to the text.  The blot works fine and timestamps are added as expected.  When the data is loaded back into the Quill editor from the database, though, instead of the timestamp value, Quill marks it as 'True' instead.  The timestamp data is saved in the database properly.  I'm having an issue figuring out how to make Quill load that data properly.

This is what the timestamp looks like in the editor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ2qI.png)

This is what it looks like when inspected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1QgZ.png)

Here's what it looks like after loading (editor view and code in inspector):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHScZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptwzu.png)

Here's the code I have for my blot currently:

```html
  var Embed = Quill.import('blots/embed');
  class QuillHashtag extends Embed {
    static create(value) {
      let node = super.create(value);
      node.innerHTML = `${value}`;
      node.setAttribute("data", value);
      return node;
    }
    static formats(node) {
      // We will only be called with a node already
      // determined to be a Link blot, so we do
      // not need to check ourselves
      return node.getAttribute('data');
    }
  }
  QuillHashtag.blotName = 'timeStamp';
  QuillHashtag.className = 'quill-hashtag';
  QuillHashtag.tagName = 'timeStamp';

  Quill.register({
    'formats/timeStamp': QuillHashtag
  });
```

Here's my code for saving the editor:

```html
  function saveTrascription() {
    var file_data = document.getElementById("transcriptEditorBox").innerHTML;
    var jobID = document.getElementById("jobSelect").value;
    var set = "set";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/transcribe/worker.php",
      data: {
        transcriptionText: file_data,
        saveTranscription: set,
        jobID: jobID
      },
      success: function (response) {
        toastr.success(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here's my code for loading the data:

```html
  function getTranscriptionJob() {
    var jobID = document.getElementById("jobSelect").value;
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audioPlayerDiv");
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (
          returnedData.transcriptionText ==
          "Transcription job not finshed. Try again shortly."
        ) {
          toastr.warning("Transcription job not finshed. Try again shortly.");

          return true;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("jobSelectRow").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("editorRow").style.display = "block";

          var delta = quill.clipboard.convert(returnedData.transcriptionText);
          quill.setContents(delta, 'silent');
          //quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(0, returnedData.transcriptionText);

          audioPlayer.innerHTML =
            '<audio onloadeddata="initProgressBar()" onplay="showPauseButton()" onpause="showPlayButton()" ontimeupdate="updateProgressBar()" controls id="audioPlayer" ><source src="' +
            returnedData.audioFile +
            '" type="audio/mpeg" >Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>';
          toastr.info("Press Alt+P to play/pause the audio file.");
          return true;
        }
      }
    };
    var url = "/transcribe/worker.php?getTranscriptionJob=set&jobID=" + jobID;
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

Any help with this is really appreciated!  I'm very lost on what is going wrong.  I think it has something to do with that formats snippet in the blot code, but not entirely sure.